# Google sheets conditional formatting quintile or percentile

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a sheet with 200 rows and many columns. For each column, I’d like to do formatting with one color for top 30, one for top 31-60, one for bottom 30, and one for bottom 31-60. I used LARGE to identify the top 30, but once I try to add a second condition the formatting goes haywire. Is there a way to accomplish this in Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a 'pair' of formula rules for each end of the scale. For one end something like:

```
=A1<SMALL(A:A,31)
```

and

```
=AND(A1<SMALL(A:A,61),A1>SMALL(A:A,30))
```

and for the 'other' end apply LARGE instead of SMALL. Make sure the ranges start at A1.